# Authentication error on App registrations

Tags: azure, authentication, entra-id

Hope this is an issue that is easily remedied.

I operate in an Azure environment where I am a global administrator as well as an Owner in various resource groups. Recently, I was asked to open App Registrations in Azure AD to reset a SPN password. When I clicked on the App Registrations option in the AAD blade, I received what looked to be a connection error banner along the top of the screen, followed by an action on my computer attempting to verify my access. I have not noticed this separate action until now.

Here below is the output of the error message that I need assistance understanding and where to locate how to fix my issue:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.10240.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1751.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.10240.16384 (th1.150709-1700)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/ownedObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application?api-version=2.0&$top=40

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/ownedObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application?api-version=2.0&$top=40 resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/ownedObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application?api-version=2.0&$top=40 did not succeed.
        + The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [6/17/2019 10:04:19 AM] : Activation of https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/ownedObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application?api-version=2.0&$top=40 has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [6/17/2019 10:04:19 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/ownedObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application?api-version=2.0&$top=40 did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Any light that can be shined to this I would greatly appreciate. I don't often go into this area so cannot determine if this was a recent development or something that has been out there a while. The only real change I have recently has been testing file shares and access to Azure storage for another project. Doubt that would have any effect, but figured I would share it here.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same behaviour trying to edit or create an App in the new AAD Portal. It only occurs in Firefox and I've got around it by disabling the "Windows Remix OneClick Helper" which fires into life on the new page. The legacy App editing page works as previously.

I believe the browser or a plugin is the issue. Have you tried editing the app properties in edge as that works for me.

I can also edit fine in Edge.

Debug from OneClick Helper brought me to your question:

> PLATFORM VERSION INFO     Windows             : 10.0.17134.0 (Win32NT)    Common
>   Language Runtime  : 4.0.30319.42000   System.Deployment.dll       :
>   4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1   clr.dll             : 4.7.3416.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_B     dfdll.dll           : 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
>     dfshim.dll          : 10.0.17134.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
>
> SOURCES   Deployment url          :
>   https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/ownedObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application?api-version=2.0&$top=40
>
> ERROR SUMMARY     Below is a summary of the errors, details of these
>   errors are listed later in the log.   * Activation of
>   https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/ownedObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application?api-version=2.0&$top=40
>   resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:      +
>   Downloading
>   https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/ownedObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application?api-version=2.0&$top=40
>   did not succeed.      + The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY   No transaction error was
>   detected.
>
> WARNINGS  There were no warnings during this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS     * [26/06/2019 13:19:51] : Activation of
>   https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/ownedObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application?api-version=2.0&$top=40
>   has started.
>
> ERROR DETAILS     Following errors were detected during this operation.
>     * [26/06/2019 13:19:51]
>   System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown
>   subtype)
>         - Downloading https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/ownedObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application?api-version=2.0&$top=40
>   did not succeed.
>         - Source: System.Deployment
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem
>   next)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
>             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState
>   subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri&
>   sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification,
>   DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore
>   subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState&
>   subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options,
>   ServerInformation& serverInformation)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore
>   subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState&
>   subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
>             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---          at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>   state)        --- Inner Exception ---         System.Net.WebException
>         - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>         - Source: System
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()          at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem
>   next)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS   No transaction information is
>   available.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, and thanks for taking the time to answer.  However, I don't see how this is an "answer"? You mention nothing that suggests how the poster's problem could be solved, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Apologies - I'd tried comment as I did intend to provide an answer. I don't believe it's AzureAD console causing the issue but the browser, in our case trying to launch a plugin which then fails.  The fix was disabling the plugin. I posted the error I received as it was so similar I believe on the limited info it fits.